# Prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} {xy\over x^2-2y}$ does not exists

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I've got a problem in proving the fact, that limit of function does not exists.
Any ideas?
It would be great.
Thanks

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} {xy\over x^2-2y}$

Comment: Can you evaluate the limit on two different paths and show different limits?

Comment: @DougM In fact as $y \to 0$ $|2y| \gg k^2y^2$, so you are seeing infinity along all those paths. The fact that this function isn't even bounded on a neighborhood of the origin makes this kind of a bad question...

Comment: @Ian I don't even understand how this question is well posed, you need to avoid paths on which the function blows up

Comment: @DougM, you evaluated the limit incorrectly: $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{ky^2}{k^2y^2+2y}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{ky}{k^2y+2}=\frac 0{0+2}=0$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

Let consider for $t\to 0$

- $x=t \quad y=t$
- $x=t\quad y=\frac{t^2}2+t^3$